# How to use a for loop to calculate daily returns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a Dataframe with shareprices from 30 companies with the following code:

```
df_2 = pd.read_csv('tickerdata.csv');
df_2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_2["Date"]);
df_2.set_index('Date')
```

Now, I need to calculate the daily log returns across all 30 columns for the different companies using a for loop. I know how to do it for a dataset with one column:

```
df_1 = np.log(p) - np.log(p).shift(1);
df_1["DJIA"] = 100 * df_1["DJIA"];
df_1 = df_1.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

However, now I need to do it for 30 columns using a for loop.. Have no idea how to do that, and after some intensive searching on google I still dont know how.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the output of `df_2.head()` in your question. That'll make this a little easier to understand.

Comment: I think you should check out [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) docs